# Does the SEIS model of disease have a disease-free equilibrium?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, mathematical-modeling, steady-state

Does the SEIS model of disease assuming a constant population and homogenous mixing have a disease-free equilibrium? I'm thinking no, because as soon as an individual "recovers" they become susceptible again and are at risk of becoming infected. How can I justify this mathematically?

My equations are:
$$ds/dt = -Asi + Ci$$
$$de/dt = -Be + Asi$$
$$di/dt = -Ci + Be$$

Where ds/dt and de/dt can be transformed into these where $R_0 = A/C$ and $s+e+i = 1$
$$ds/dt = -A(1-s-e)(s-1/R_0)$$
$$de/dt = As(1-s-e)-Be$$

When I produce a phase-plane of e vs s, I get. The nullcines don't intersect at (1,0), but they are very close (1,-1.78508E-20). Do I count this as (1,0) and thus a disease-free state?

[image: phase-plane]

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the following SEIS model:
\begin{align*}
{\tfrac  {dS}{dT}}&=B-\beta SI-\mu S+\gamma I\\
{\tfrac  {dE}{dT}}&=\beta SI-(\epsilon +\mu )E\\
{\tfrac  {dI}{dT}}&=\varepsilon E-(\gamma +\mu )I
\end{align*}
Setting $E=I=0$ and $dS/dT=0$ gives an equilibrium $B=\mu S,$ that is, $S=B/\mu.$ It's the same as if the disease never existed.

Comment: What are mew and epsilon?

Comment: $\mu$ is natural death rate, $\epsilon$ is extra death rate for the exposed population. This is just copied from Wikipedia - you should really include the equations you use in the question.

Comment: I will do so now.

Comment: So I have added the equations. When I produce a phase plane of them with arbitarary values for A, B and C, (which are just the rates of moving from Susceptible to Exposed, Exposed to Infectious and Infectious to Susceptible respectively), I get a disease-free equilibrium for $R_0 < 1$ but when $R_0 > 1$, I get an endemic equilibrium and what appears to be an equilibrium (1, -1.78508E-20). Do I count this as (1,0) and thus a disease-free equilibrium because it's so close to (1,0) or do I ignore it because it's out of physical bounds? If I don't ignore it, then how can I mathematically justify?

Comment: @Curious: Mathematically an equilibrium is just a fixed point - any $(S,E,I)$ where $dS/dT=dE/dT=dI/dT=0.$ It might be a stable equilibrium or it might not -that is a further property.